# Making "for" loop faster

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, subprocess, mpi4py

I am trying to run this code on a large 3D dataset. The goal is to calculate the time correlation (axis 0) of each grid point against all the other grid points. I thought of doing as the code below: two loops, one in each dimension. This is OK for small datasets but now I moved on to larger resolution and it is taking days to run.

```
    for lat in range(latitude.shape[0]):
        print('-->lat_points = ' + str(lat) + '/' +
              str(latitude.shape[0]))
        for lon in range(longitude.shape[0]):
            print ('lon_points = ' + str(lon) + '/' +
                   str(longitude.shape[0]))
            corr = correlation(sub_cube1[:, lat, lon], sub_cube2)
            rho[lat, lon] = corr.min()
            vec_lat[lat, lon] = np.where(corr == corr.min())[0]
            vec_lon[lat, lon] = np.where(corr == corr.min())[1]
```

Can anyone advise on speeding this up/ optimizing this code, keeping in mind I only have access to the standard python libraries (so no mpi4py!)?

`correlation` function uses `pandas` to calculate the correlation coefficient between the two time series:

```
corr_coef = np.empty(shape=series1[0, ].shape)
for j in range(series1.shape[-2]):
    for k in range(series1.shape[-1]):
        apd = pd.Series(series1[:, j, k])
        bpd = pd.Series(series2[:, j, k])
        corr_coef[j, k] = apd.corr(bpd)
```

Thanks

Comment: Removing print statements will speed it up

Comment: It is fine that ur script take time for large dataset. Script should not take much memory due to wrong algorithm or coding. Need  definition of `correlation` function. Also need to know time vs input details. Related to code use xrange(in python 2.7, in Python 3.x xpath is removed. ). because this will return xrange object while range return list.

Comment: @VivekSable, I have added the info on the 'correlation' function

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using a nested list comprehension:

```
[[correlation(sub_cube1[:, lat, lon], sub_cube2).min() 
  for lon in xrange(longitude.shape[0])] 
 for lat in xrange(latitude.shape[0])]
```

Comment: I had previously simplified the loop and removed some of the statements as I know from testing the code that they do not significantly add to the time needed to run, but which I believe makes your suggestion impossible to apply. However, really useful for other stuff, thanks :-)